# Combine multiple enumerate with \paragraph

Tags: sectioning, enumerate, sections-paragraphs

I am trying to use `\paragraph` inside of an `enumerate` environment, but I keep getting a
`! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.`

Using multiple `enumerate`s, whether nested or sequentially, seems to trigger this.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

  \begin{enumerate}
    \paragraph{A.1}%This works
    \item
    Working.
  \end{enumerate}

  \paragraph{B}
    This combined with the next enumerate (in any order) allows {\textbackslash}paragraph to work again.
  \begin{enumerate}
%     \paragraph{C.1}%TODO this command breaks: ! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.
    \item
    Broken.
  \end{enumerate}

    \begin{enumerate}
    \paragraph{D.1}%This also works
    \item
    Also working.
      \begin{enumerate}
%           \subparagraph{D.1.a}%TODO this command breaks: ! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.
      \item
      Broken.
      \end{enumerate}
  \end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Note `\paragraph` is a 4th level section heading intended to be used in the sequesnce section, subsection, subsubsection, paragraph, subparagraph

Comment: If you increase `\setcounter{secnumdepth}[4}` you will see ` \paragraph{D.1}` produces something weird, it's like using `\section{D}` and a mix of automatic and manual numbering

Comment: The body of `enumerate` always has to be a list of `\item` the fact that sometimes it fails to give an error message if a section heading is used before the  `\item` is an implementation detail that you should not rely on.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!